# lapply, rowSums and passign arguments

Tags: r, lapply, rowsum

Consider this code

```
lapply(lst,rowSums)
```

`lst` is a list of **five** data frames. Each data frame has, for example, **four** columns and **ten** rows. I want to add the values of the columns in each row, however, I do not want to include the value of **column one** in the sum.

I can use a `for` loop and the code below:

```
lst_sum = list()
for (ii in c(1,5))
{
 dummy <- lst[[ii]]
 dummy <- rowSums(dummy[,seq(2,4,by = 1)])
 lst_sum[[ii]] = dummy 
 }
```

I would like to use `lapply` or a similar function because I think the `for` loops looks ugly and inefficient.

Comment: Try something like `lapply(lst, function(x) rowSums(x[, -1]))`? More fully reproducible example for what you need is: `df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, z = 1:10); 
l = list(df, df, df, df, df); 
lapply(l, function(x) rowSums(x[, -1]));`

Comment: Did you meant `Reduce("+", lst)`  It is not clear without a reproducible example  Or try `lapply(lapply(lst, "[", -1), rowSums)`

Answer (score 0):

With the help of comments I got this solution:

```
 lapply(lst,function(x) rowSums(x[,seq(2,4,by = 1)]))
```